# Curling stones: There seems to be an electronic thing in the stone, why?

Tags: curling

Olympic stones seem to have 2 green lights on it, and it would be weird to have 2 dels light up if there are nothing else electronically speaking in the stone.

So what are the electronics in the stone, and what do they serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "[Eye on the Hog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_on_the_Hog)". It enforces the requirement that the stone must be released before the hog line to be valid.

Comment: And as an aside, the electronics are solely in the handle, *not* in the stone.